# untiy3d water is pink

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> system error saying 'float3 × 4' not supported and Shader error in 'FX / Water': 'tex2Dproj': no matching 2 parameter intrinsic function; Possible intrinsic functions are: tex2Dproj (sampler2D, float4 | half4 | min10float4 | min16float4) at line 143 (on d3d11_9x)

[image]

> 1.'float3 × 4' not supported

```
    #if defined (HAS_REFLECTION) || defined (HAS_REFRACTION)
// calculate the reflection vector
float3x4 mat = float3x4 (
    0.5, 0, 0, 0.5,
    0, 0.5 * _ProjectionParams.x, 0, 0.5,
    0, 0, 0, 1
);
```

> 2. 'tex2Dproj': no matching 2 parameter intrinsic function

```
    half4 refl = tex2Dproj( _ReflectionTex, uv1 );
```

I do not know how to resolve these two errors.Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: A little more background would be useful

Comment: Now it seems to be downloaded water resource bundle because unity3d version update There are two errors not running.

Comment: Title: Pink means shader didn't compile. They use pink because you see it instantly. 
You can try to use: `#pragma target 3.0`